14” wheels on a 16” bike for toddlers
I purchased a 16” bike for my 4 year old granddaughter, who currently rides her 14” without training wheels.  I wanted to get her the next size up to grow in to.  Her toes barely touch the ground on the 16’ bike, so would it be possible to exchange the wheels out temporarily to the 14” wheels until she grows a bit, so she can use it now?

The main problems would be ground clearance, possibly tyre/frame clearance, and whether the chain lines up.   Also in extreme turns there is more chance of pedal-ground strike.
It is possible the two bikes use different standards for hub width or chain offset.
Your best option is to just try it and see what happens.  Worst case, it doesn't work and you revert.
No matter what, you get to spend some time with the granddaugher trying this out, involving her in the process.
Do please update us with progress after you've tried it.

It's moderately likely that the wheels will physically fit but the brake reach will be longer, probably requiring new brakes and the cranks will likely be too long for small person legs and as noted problems with pedals striking the ground are likely.

@Noise I wasn't too worried with the brake.  99% likely the bike has a rear coaster brake, and hand brakes are generally beyond what most kids can use effectively.   I'd suspect this isn't going to be used on a road.   Good point about the crank lengths though.    Give the kid 2 months and she'll probably fit fine - kids grow like weeds at that age.

As far as crank lengths go, kids at that age have astounding flexibility and unlikely to have developed good enough pedal technique for it to make a difference.
